# Split columns names cannot be renamed

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have successfully expanded one address column into four. However, the new dataframe has default column names of integers 0-3. I have tried to rename these columns, but the new dataframe with renamed columns is not reflecting the change. The column names remain integers 0-3.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/kdavid3mbp/Python/ketamine_data.csv')
data['usecase_one'] = data['usecase_one'].str.replace('For', '', regex=True)
data['usecase_one'] = data['usecase_one'].str.replace(':', '', regex=True)
data['usecase_two'] = data['usecase_two'].str.replace('For', '', regex=True)
data['usecase_two'] = data['usecase_two'].str.replace(':', '', regex=True)

address = data['address'].str.split('\n', expand=True)

new_address = address.rename(columns={
    '0': 'Clinic Name',
    '1': 'Street',
    '2': 'City_State_Country',
    '3': 'Misc Address'
})

new_address
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using integers instead of strs? I.e. `0`, instead of `"0"`.

Comment: What does this have to do with web scraping? You're reading a local CSV file, not an HTML web page.

Comment: Why do you use `regex=True` when it's not a regex? BTW, `regex=True` is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reassign column headers like so:

```
new_address = address.set_axis(['Clinic Name',
                                'Street',
                                'City_State_Country',
                                'Misc Address'], axis=1, copy=False)
```

Note:

> FutureWarning: DataFrame.set_axis 'inplace' keyword is deprecated and
> will be removed in a future version. Use `obj = obj.set_axis(..., copy=False)` instead.

you could also just use the columns attribute:

```
address.columns = (['Clinic Name',
                    'Street',
                    'City_State_Country',
                    'Misc Address'])
```